# Confusing Inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Here is the code I was looking, [Source code](http://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp) :

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
```

if we instantiate it with some functor `X` i.e `function_traits<X>;` , That will build the base class which is  `function_traits<decltype(&X::operator())>` due to inheritance , but to build `function_traits<decltype(&X::operator())>` it's base also has to be built, which could be `function_traits<decltype(Z)>`

I understand `function_traits<X>` != `function_traits<Z>`. Isn't that recursive inheritance? 0_o.
How all things is working together?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. This isn't valid code without some other specialization of `function_traits` for member function pointers.

Comment: @FreakEnum : Yes, that code contains the exact specializations I was referring to. ;-]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show us a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is illegal code. You cannot derive from an incomplete type, and at the point you try to derive from `function_traits`, the type is incomplete.

```
struct A { typedef A type; };
struct B { typedef A type; };

template <typename T>
struct X : X<typename T::type> {};

X<B> test; // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct X<A>’
```

The only way you could get round this is if the `function_traits` you are trying to derive from is a complete type. You can do this using specialisation:

```
struct A { typedef A type; };
struct B { typedef A type; };

template <typename T>
struct X : X<typename T::type> {};

template <>
struct X<A> {}; // X<A> is now a complete type.

X<B> test; // OK! Derives from X<A>, which is complete.
```

Here, `X<A>` is complete when you try to derive from it, so you're fine.

Comment: here is the whole If you might wanna look http://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp

Comment: @FreakEnum: As you can see, he specialises the template for various types of functions below the first definition, so he always has a complete class. I'm sure KennyTM will answer any other questions you have :-) http://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm

Comment: Now that made sense to me. Thank you:)

Comment: "_This is illegal code._" The code shown is incomplete. How can you say it is not legal? "_the type is incomplete_" But what's a complete type? We do not have enough information.

Comment: @curiousguy: True, but when I posted there was no link to the source, so I assumed it was the whole code.

Comment: @curiousguy He is right, it was my mistake that I didn't post the whole code.